# Conversion of Outlook data to xml in mono

Tags: monodevelop

I am in the process of converting a C# application from windows to mono.  Is there an equivalent resource in linux to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook?  Part of the application converts the data in an Outlook calendar to xml.

Answer (score 0):

http://mono-project.com/Main_Page

There is a cross platform Distropackage for older ubuntu like 12.04. 
Since there is debian packages for Ubuntu older release.

I did not get info what version of Ubuntu you are using to convert Mono files from c#,
I have not had time to test this out to check if it runs in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
How ever i know that old dependencies should work from 12.04

I personally use codelight when needing migrate things between platforms.
http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-codelite-5-4-ubuntu-debian-linux-mint/

That one works for sure.
Or you can get this also.
http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-premake4-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/
or
This one i use daily in my work. It definetley will resolve your need and some.
http://www.unixmen.com/install-codeblocks-ide-ubuntuelementaryosdebian/

Let us know if this did not resolve things for you.